# Popup in onPostExecute

Tags: android, popupmenu

As the onPostExecute of an AsyncTask runs on the UIthread, it should be possible to add a PopupMenu in it. But when I do so, I get a compiler error that I don't know how to fix:
`The constructor PopupMenu(My.....dothedirectionTHREAD, View) is undefined`

The line of code is:

```
PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(this, findViewById(R.id.reset));
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `this`, try `getApplicationContext` or `getBaseContext`.

`this` in this example does nor refer to the `context`.

Answer (score 0):

`this` refers to AsyncTask but you need Activity context. Try below or your Activity class.

```
PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(MainActivity.this, findViewById(R.id.reset));
```

Answer (score 0):

In this line

```
PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(this, findViewById(R.id.reset));
```

the `this` pointer is referring to your AsyncTask class, which is not valid as a Context.

Assuming your AsyncTask is an inner class in your Activity, you should use something like this:

```
PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(MyActivity.this, findViewById(R.id.reset));
```

Answer (score 0):

I would guess, that you have to use your appcontext instead of "this" which delivers in your case the Thread and not the context.

```
PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(context, findViewById(R.id.reset));
```

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupMenu.html